# ¿Como añadir el driver de UcanAccess a Jaspersoft Studio?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Buenas!

Estoy empezando a ver como se pueden crear reportes para mi programa en JAVA y di con un plugin para netbeans llamado "iReport" y las librerias Jasper para ello. En esta misma web me di cuenta de que el plugin ya no tiene soporte desde el 2015 y que deberia mejor descargarme su software aparte llamado "Jaspersoft Studio".

Mi programa esta usando una base de datos creado en Access... y en ese Jaspersoft Studio veo que tiene incorporado puros drivers para SQL. Al parecer tengo que añadir dicho driver de UcanAccess, pero como puedo añadir eso al programa para poder conectarme con mi base de datos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, ya he dado como añadirlo y os comparto con vosotros:

1. En JasperStudio buscan el icono de añadir un nuevo DataAdapter (add new DataAdapter).
2. Le asignan un nombre al archivo xml que quieran.
3. Siguiente ventana les piden de donde van a sacar los datos... ustedes eligen la opcion "Database JDBC Connection".
4. Le asignan un nombre a su conexion y seguidamente dan clic donde dice "Driver Classpath".
5. Acto seguido añadiremos los siguientes archivos jar que obtenemos al descargar UcanAccess:

En la carpeta lib añadimos todos los jar que contiene (common-lang,common-logging,hsqldb,jackess) y por ultimo, un jar que se llama UcanAccess (apenas abres la carpeta que descargaste, es el primero que vas a ver).

6. Regresamos a Database location y en el campo "JDBC Driver" colocamos lo siguiente: `net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver`
7. Por ultimo, en el campo "JDBC Url" tendremos que insertarle la direccion de nuestra base de datos. Y la sintaxis para señalarlo es el siguiente:

   jdbc:ucanaccess:RutaDeTuMSAccessDB;showSchema=true

Y ya con esto, si hiciste todo bien, al pulsar "test" Jasper  te debe responder con algo asi como "Successfully".